# How to change the interpretation of a variable in `zsh`?

Tags: command-line, zsh

I set a variable `TEMPP='-I ../dir1 -I ../dir2'`

then I run

`gcc -M $TEMPP somefile.c`

It seems not to include `../dir1` and `../dir2` in the search list of the include file, and if there is a space at the beginning of the variable, like

`TEMPP=' -I ../dir1 -I ../dir2'`

it reports an error:

`gcc:  -I ../common1 -I ../encrypt: No such file or directory`

so it seems the variable was treated as a file.

Maybe it will let me separate the directory to avoid this promblem, but those included `dirs` are generated by another command, and the amount is not constant.

So how can I let a variable in a command be treated as literal seem like a manual input in command line, not an integral string or a file name?

OK...I find this situation only happened in the `zsh`, but in bash it works well...
may be in `zsh` the expansion of variable is special.

So if anyone can tell me how can this work well in zsh I will appreciate, or I can only do this in bash.

Comment: Your example, as written, should work fine.  Please provide the actual command you are running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In zsh, unlike other Bourne-style shells, the results of a variable substitution are not split into words that are interpreted as wildcard patterns. So in zsh, if you write

```
a='hello *.txt'
echo $a
```

then you see `hello *.txt`, unlike other shells where you'll see something like `hello bar.txt foo.txt`.

You can turn on word splitting for one [expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) with `$=TEMPP`. You can turn on word splitting for all expansions with `setopt sh_word_split` or `emulate sh`.

You should stick these commands in a makefile and let a real Bourne-style shell (whatever is installed as `/bin/sh`) run them. Keep zsh for interactive use and your own scripts.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is solve my `zsh` problem, and yes, in makefile there is no that problem, in the beginning I use makefile to test these command, it works well, but for some reason I need to run these command in command line, then I run it in `zsh` and found it works differ from makefile. Thanks for your answer and advice.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're trying to control whether white space in `"$TEMPP"` is interpreted or not.  (Note, this is not a GCC problem, it is your shell that is parsing the command line.)

Here is what `bash` does:

```
$ F="foo bar baz"
$ for f in $F; do echo $f; done
foo
bar
baz
```

And here is what `zsh` does:

```
$ F="foo bar baz"
$ for f in $F; do echo $f; done
foo bar baz
```

You need to get `zsh` to interpret the whitespace.  There may be a graceful way to do this in zsh (I don't know, but if you re-title and tag your question, you might get more useful answers).  This should work around the problem, but is a bit of a heavy hammer for this problem:

```
eval gcc -M $TEMPP somefile.c
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, at first I don't know the problem is because of `zsh`, so the title is this, and then I find this work well in `bash` and I make a supplements in the end, but I did not consider about the title.And thanks for you solution about `eval`, it works.

Answer (score 0):

A variable that holds a variable number of values is called an array.

```
var=value
```

Is scalar variable assignment syntax, where *one* value is assigned to a *scalar variable*.

```
var=( one two 'three or 3' )
```

Is *array variable* assignment syntax¹, where you can assign *any number* (even 0²) of values to an *array/list variable*.

```
var[n]=foo
```

Is also scalar assignment syntax but assigns *one* value to the n<sup>th</sup> element³ of the array.

So, here you want:

```
extra_options=( -I ../dir1 -I ../dir2 -I '/opt/my software/include' )
```

```
gcc -M $extra_options somefile.c
```

Note that `$extra_options` expansion skips the empty elements of the `$extra_options` array if any, like `$scalar` expands to *no* argument rather than one empty element if `$scalar` is empty.

You need `"$scalar"` or `"$array[@]"` or `"${(@)array}"` (or `"${array[@]}"`, compatible with ksh-like shells such as bash and reminiscent of the `"$@"` of the Bourne shell) to preserve the empty elements.

Note that in other Bourne-like shells, in:

```
TEMPP='-I ../dir1 -I ../dir2'
gcc -M $TEMPP somefile.c
```

`$TEMPP` undergoes an implicit so-called *split+glob* operator, it is not (thankfully!) as if the value of `$TEMPP` had been embedded as-is in the shell code like in `gcc -M -I ../dir1 -I ../dir2 somefile.c`.

If it were the case<sup>4</sup>, with:

```
TEMPP='foo>/etc/passwd;reboot' # or '$(reboot>/etc/passwd)'
echo $TEMPP
```

Would overwrite `/etc/passwd` and reboot for instance. Shell syntax including `;`, `>` operators, `${...}`, `$(...)` expansions, quotes is not recognised or handled upon variable expansions. It's however not expanded as-is like in zsh or other saner modern shells (like rc, es, fish, akanga...) or other programming languages, but undergoes that split+glob operator.

The value of `$TEMPP` is only split on characters of `$IFS` and then subject to globbing (aka filename generation or pathname expansion). What that means is that:

```
TEMPP='-I ../dir1 -I ../dir2'
gcc -M $TEMPP somefile.c
```

Only works if `$IFS`, at the point of interpreting the `gcc...` line happens to contain the space character and doesn't contain any of the other characters in `$TEMPP` (thankfully, that's the case with the  default value of `$IFS`). For instance, if `$IFS` contained `i` instead, `gcc` would be called with `-I ../d`, `r1 -I ../d` and `r2` arguments instead.

And:

```
TEMPP='-I ../dir1 -I ../dir2 -I "/opt/my software/include"'
gcc -M $TEMPP somefile.c
```

Wouldn't work, as we just have splitting on `$IFS`, not interpretation of shell syntax such as quoting, so if you had to pass arguments containing spaces, you'd need a different separator for the splitting such as:

```
TEMPP='-I,../dir1,-I,../dir2,-I,/opt/my software/include'
IFS=,
gcc -M $TEMPP somefile.c
```

For instance. And if you had values containing globbing operators such as `*`, `?`, `[...]`, you would need to issue a `set -o noglob` command before the expansion to make sure globs are not expanded. See also [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) for the security implications of that misdesign of Bourne-like shells (other than zsh).

In zsh, if you want `$IFS`-splitting and/or globbing (but you generally don't as zsh like most other modern shells has arrays), you have to request it *explicitly*, `$=scalar` to split on `$IFS`, `$~scalar` for the contents of `$scalar` to be considered as a pattern and subject to globbing or `$=~scalar` to have both and therefore the equivalent of `$scalar` in other Bourne-like shells.

See also `${(s[whatever])scalar}` to split on arbitrary separators instead of `$IFS`, with `${(f)scalar}` and `${(0)scalar}` as shorthands to split on line`f`eed (aka newline) or NULs.

And if you need `zsh` to interpret code written for other Bourne-like or Korn-like shells, you'd use its `sh` or `ksh` emulations where compatibility with those shells is improved with:

- `emulate ksh`: change the emulation definitely (though `emulate zsh` would restore the default saner mode.
- `emulate -L ksh`: same but only `L`ocally (in the current function for instance).
- `emulate ksh -c 'ksh/bash code here'` or `emulate ksh -c 'source some-ksh-or-bash-script'` to interpret only the given code in that emulation mode.

In sh or ksh emulation, IFS-splitting and globbing are done implicitly upon unquoted parameter expansions in list contexts like in sh/ksh/bash (the `shwordsplit` and `globsubst` and many other options that affect the behaviour of the shell are tweaked to align with the behaviour of those other shells as closely as possible).

---

<sup>¹ inspired by the `set var = ( one two 'three or 3' )` of csh, the first shell to introduce arrays and later copied by other shells like ksh93 (though earlier versions of ksh had `set -A var one two 'three or 3'` for  that), bash or yash.</sup>

<sup>² note: in ksh93, `var=()` without declaring `var` as array first creates a *compound* variable rather than an array variable.</sup>

<sup>³ [in zsh and all other shells but with one exception](/a/252405): ksh (and bash which copied ksh instead of zsh), where instead array indices start at 0 and arrays are sparse, so `array[1]=x` would assign the second element if the one with index 0 was also set, and `array[123]=x` would assign the first element if all those from 0 to 122 were not otherwise set.</sup>

<sup><sup>4</sup>actually, that was the case in the first (very simple and primitive) Unix shell from the early 70s which didn't have variables nor command substitution but had `$1`...`$9` positional parameters which expanded like that.</sup>